# Save a number of different transactions example (trans1, trans2, trans3) + write to json

Tags: python

```
import datetime
import json
print ('--------------- Crptocurrency Transfer --------------- \n')

name = 'y'


while name != 'n':

# add name of the sender

print (' Enter the name of the sender: ')
sender = input("\n")

# add name of reciever #

print (' Enter the name of the receiver: ')
receiver = input("\n")

# how much would you like to send #

print (' How much would you like to send :$ ')
amount = str(input("\n"))

# save details to a log and append to text file 

trans1 = [
    {"sender": sender},
    {"receiver": receiver},
    {"amount": amount}
    ]

# ask if any more transactions, if no then end program

name = input (' Are there any more transactions? ( Enter y or n ): ')


with open('TransactionHistory.json', 'w') as th:
     json.dump(trans1, th)
```

save all transactions( example, trans1, trans2, trans3) different names & different amounts to json as long as user keeps entering y and then open json file in another py program to use transaction data

Comment: and to add current date time to each transaction, had issues with json serialization

Comment: it should be `json.dump` not `json.dumps`

Comment: This code doesn't run as is, but when I removed `print(record)` and replaced `record` with `trans1` on the last line, it all worked just fine, terminating when I entered `n`. Please update the example to fail as you are saying that it does.

Comment: With the latest update, the code won't dump the last transaction to the JSON file, as it will break right before it.

Comment: are you running this code on windows? IIRC, the input function on windows doesn't remove the '\r' (carriage return). I don't have access to A windows computer to test, but add `print repr(name)` before the end of the loop and see if it looks like 'n\r'.  If if does you will need to do `name.rstrip()` to remove the stray carriage return

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach works, there's just a few bugs e.g. header (import and first print), print (record) rather than print (trans1) etc... You originally used `break`, I think `!= 'n'` is a bit more pythonic.

Second request, you need to initialize the file (in this case you've already done it,

```
with open('TransactionHistory.json', mode='w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump([], f)
```

Once the file exists you append within the loop, there is no other way and this approach will be slow.

```
import json

print ('--------------- Crptocurrency Transfer --------------- ')

name = ''

with open('TransactionHistory.json', mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as feedsjson:
    feeds = json.load(feedsjson)

while name != 'n':
    print (' Enter the name of the sender: ')
    sender = input("\n")
    print (' Enter the name of the receiver: ')
    receiver = input("\n")
    print (' How much would you like to send :$ ')
    amount = str(input("\n"))
    name = input (' Are there any more transactions? ( Enter y or n ): ')
#    trans1 = [
#            {"sender": sender},
#            {"receiver": receiver},
#            {"amount": amount}
#    ]
    with open('TransactionHistory.json', "w") as myjson:
        entry =   {"sender": sender, "receiver": receiver, "amount": amount}
        feeds.append(entry)
        json.dump (feeds, myjson)

# Check that the json db is okay    
with open('TransactionHistory.json', "r") as f:
    data= json.load(f)
    print ("Done\n")
```

**Output,** Done

Comment: created the file but cant print contents from another py program, I tried json.dumps and json.load?

Comment: Oh ... okay you need to rewrite the subroutine to append the dictionary within the while loop

Comment: Okay done it ... just make sure the json db is initialised before appending to it